# Changing activeadmin use of model name to another method in forms and show pages

Tags: activeadmin

ActiveAdmin seems to use #name as a default #to_s method to present in a few places, but this isn't the case with our data model.

I found adding `to_label` on the model fixes forms, thanks to formtastic, but haven't seen a way in the docs to do this for ActiveAdmin itself, e.g. in its show pages. Is there a configuration I didn't see, or do we need to override/reimplement all the stuff that uses #name?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the name of the model in a translation file:

- Create a file: `config/locales/activerecord.en.yml`
- Instead of `en` you should use your own local in the file name
- In the .yml file:

> ```
> en:
>   activerecord:
>     models:
>       your_original_model_name: 'Your custom model name'
>       ...
> ```

Comment: That looks like it's customising the class name? I want to change how instances are summarised as strings by ActiveAdmin in its default show pages.

Comment: I want to change the method being used to "serialise" records for display in e.g. belongs-to relationship links.

Comment: Have you tried override the to_s method in the ActiveRecord model?